# Grand Theft Auto V - cloud save?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, steam-cloud, rockstar-games-social-club

Is the save file kept in Rockstar's cloud service, or is it stored locally on the hard drive?

Answer (score -3):

Its stored in the cloud on the hard drive.

Comment: Could add some more to your answer, such where you found this information?

Comment: Steam cloud is an external storage service. Its not located on the user's computer.

Comment: This answer contradicts itself. Cloud is external, hard drive is local. So which is it?

Comment: I asked my sister she said on the hard drive..